# DJI Assistant 2 simulator will not run missions. DJI ERROR 5021 "TOTAL MISSION DISTANCE TOO LARGE"

Tags: swift, simulation, dji-sdk

So I have been writing an application to run custom missions, the missions run fine and everything works as intended, however when attempting to run on the simulator I receive this error.

The missions should not be considered too large as I calculate distance at 1081m and attempting to physically run this mission succeeds. Trying to do the same in the simulator is resulting in error code 5021.

If it is helpful I also get error code 1003 "This process has timed out"

Any help with this would be appreciated as I have spent much time trying to solve this issue.

I can provide further info if needed however nothing seems relevant at this time except that which I have said.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the **waypoint** function to let the drone move with pre-defined latitude and longitude? If the answer is yes! then possibly that because the constant latitude and longitude in the GUI of the simulator are far from your **GPS** points.
And this is not allowed from the SDK for safety reasons.

So, basically, it is not allowed to set **waypoints** far from the Home location (the location where the drone would take off from)

Answer (score 0):

As Mohamad Ghaith Alzin mentioned, maybe the waypoints in your mission are too far away from the home located in the simulator. You can try to set the location in the simulator to the location of the first/start waypoint. You can do it before starting the simulator like below:
[the simulator GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBRrS.png)